# Query to check multiple attributes in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to retrieve a list of items based on `loggedInUserId`. Below is a rough schema I have

```
{
personId: 1,
accountManagerId: 2,
accountExecId: 3,
successManagerId: 5
}
```

I want to retrieve all the records if `loggedInUserId` is any of above mentioned fields. What will be the best way to organize the data?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

We you have two options.

One would look something like

```
PK                 SK            PersonId AccountManagerId AccountExecId SuccessManagerId
<partition value>  <sort value>  1        2                3             5
```

The other would be to just store the whole object in a json string

```
PK                SK             UserData
<partition value> <sort value>   <user data>
```

I prefer the second one, but both are valid

Edit:

For querying, if you want to search by the *loggedInUserId* you can set it as a partition key

```
PK=LOGGED_IN_USER_ID#1
```

And a simple Java example for query

```
    var dynamoClient = DynamoDbEnhancedClient.builder().dynamoDbClient(dynamoDbClient).build();
    
    var table = dynamoClient.table("Users", TableSchema.fromClass(Users.class));
    table.getItem(Key.builder().partitionValue("1").build());
```

Its easier to use string partition and sort keys

Comment: How will I go about querying the data? If loggedInUserId is 1, I want to retrieve all the records which has 1 in any of those fields. I want to use query rather than scanning

Comment: If loggedInUserId is part of your access patterns, then it has to be included in the PK or SK. loggedInUserId sounds like a good candidate for a PK I will update my answers

Answer (score 0):

Typically in DynamoDB you denormalize the data, unlike the normalized schema you show. That would look like the following:

```
pk  | sk               | data
1   | personId         | other info
1   | accountManagerId | other info
2   | personId         | other info
4   | successManagerId | other info
```

Now if you have a `loggedInUserId` as 1 and you do a `Query` API call to your table you get all the items that user relates to.

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE pk= 1`

```
1   | personId         | other info
1   | accountManagerId | other info
```